# Статус: 400 Сообщение: Bad request ,Ошибка: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@41c12f88

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Здравствуйте пытаюсь разобраться с API ucoz, но никак не могу получить 200 статус при обращении к сервису. Пример удачного ответа в json-формате:

```
    {
     "page":1, 
     "pages_list":"1..32", 
     "per_page":"1", 
     "news":[{
     "other3":"a",
     "reads":20,
     "other5":"s",
     "avatar":"d",
     "other1":"g",
     "rate_num":0,
     "author":"Dmitry_DM",
     "comments":"yes",
     "rating":"0.00",
     "add_date":"2016-03-26 16:23",
     "rate_sum":0,
     "category":{
        "url":"http://yoursite.ucoz.ru/category/hello",
        "name":"Категория",
        "id":1,
        "description":"39_e"
     },
     "id":"61",
     "ontop":"no",
     "other4":"q",
     "other2":"f",
     "pending":"no",
     "entry_url":"http://yoursite.ucoz.ru/news/test/2016-03-26-61",
     "message":"аыва",
     "title":"тест",
     "hgu_title":"test" 
      } 
      ], 
      "total_news":32
      }
```

Или неудачного:

```
      {"error":{"msg":"Missing required parameter","code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER"}}
```

POJO-объект такой:

```
 public class UcozApi {

@SerializedName("page")
@Expose
private Integer page;
@SerializedName("pages_list")
@Expose
private String pagesList;
@SerializedName("per_page")
@Expose
private String perPage;
@SerializedName("news")
@Expose
private List<News> news = new ArrayList<News>();
@SerializedName("total_news")
@Expose
private Integer totalNews;
@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
private Error error;


public Integer getPage() {
    return page;
}


public void setPage(Integer page) {
    this.page = page;
}


public String getPagesList() {
    return pagesList;
}


public void setPagesList(String pagesList) {
    this.pagesList = pagesList;
}


public String getPerPage() {
    return perPage;
}


public void setPerPage(String perPage) {
    this.perPage = perPage;
}


public List<News> getNews() {
    return news;
}


public void setNews(List<News> news) {
    this.news = news;
}


public Integer getTotalNews() {
    return totalNews;
}


public void setTotalNews(Integer totalNews) {
    this.totalNews = totalNews;
}


public Error getError() {
    return error;
}


public void setError(Error error) {
    this.error = error;
} 
}


public class News {
@SerializedName("other3")
@Expose
private String other3;
@SerializedName("reads")
@Expose
private Integer reads;
@SerializedName("other5")
@Expose
private String other5;
@SerializedName("avatar")
@Expose
private String avatar;
@SerializedName("other1")
@Expose
private String other1;
@SerializedName("rate_num")
@Expose
private Integer rateNum;
@SerializedName("author")
@Expose
private String author;
@SerializedName("comments")
@Expose
private String comments;
@SerializedName("rating")
@Expose
private String rating;
@SerializedName("add_date")
@Expose
private String addDate;
@SerializedName("rate_sum")
@Expose
private Integer rateSum;
@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
private Category category;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("ontop")
@Expose
private String ontop;
@SerializedName("other4")
@Expose
private String other4;
@SerializedName("other2")
@Expose
private String other2;
@SerializedName("pending")
@Expose
private String pending;
@SerializedName("entry_url")
@Expose
private String entryUrl;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("hgu_title")
@Expose
private String hguTitle;


public String getOther3() {
    return other3;
}


public void setOther3(String other3) {
    this.other3 = other3;
}


public Integer getReads() {
    return reads;
}


public void setReads(Integer reads) {
    this.reads = reads;
}


public String getOther5() {
    return other5;
}


public void setOther5(String other5) {
    this.other5 = other5;
}


public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}


public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}


public String getOther1() {
    return other1;
}


public void setOther1(String other1) {
    this.other1 = other1;
}


public Integer getRateNum() {
    return rateNum;
}


public void setRateNum(Integer rateNum) {
    this.rateNum = rateNum;
}


public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}


public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}


public String getComments() {
    return comments;
}


public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}


public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}


public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}


public String getAddDate() {
    return addDate;
}


public void setAddDate(String addDate) {
    this.addDate = addDate;
}


public Integer getRateSum() {
    return rateSum;
}


public void setRateSum(Integer rateSum) {
    this.rateSum = rateSum;
}


public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}


public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}


public String getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getOntop() {
    return ontop;
}


public void setOntop(String ontop) {
    this.ontop = ontop;
}


public String getOther4() {
    return other4;
}


public void setOther4(String other4) {
    this.other4 = other4;
}


public String getOther2() {
    return other2;
}


public void setOther2(String other2) {
    this.other2 = other2;
}


public String getPending() {
    return pending;
}


public void setPending(String pending) {
    this.pending = pending;
}


public String getEntryUrl() {
    return entryUrl;
}


public void setEntryUrl(String entryUrl) {
    this.entryUrl = entryUrl;
}


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}


public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


public String getHguTitle() {
    return hguTitle;
}


public void setHguTitle(String hguTitle) {
    this.hguTitle = hguTitle;
}
}

public class Category {
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;


public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}


public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}


public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}

public class Error {
@SerializedName("msg")
@Expose
private String msg;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;


public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}


public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}


public String getCode() {
    return code;
}


public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
}
```

Интерфейс:

```
public interface UcozNewsService {
@GET("news/")
Call<UcozApi> getNews(
@Query("oauth_consumer_key") String oauth_consumer_key,
@Query("oauth_consumer_secret") String oauth_consumer_secret,
@Query("oauth_token") String oauth_token,
@Query("oauth_token_secret") String oauth_token_secret);
}
```

Код в самом классе:

```
....
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://pikasso.3dn.ru/uapi/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            UcozNewsService ucozNewsService = retrofit.create(UcozNewsService.class);
            Call<UcozApi> call = ucozNewsService.getNews(consumerKey, consumerSecret, oAuthToken, oAuthTokenSecret);
            try {
                call.enqueue(new Callback<UcozApi>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UcozApi> call, Response<UcozApi> response) {
                        try {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                UcozApi ucozApi = response.body();
                                Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + ucozApi.getError().getMsg() + " Code: " + ucozApi.getError().getCode());

                            } else {
                                int status = response.code();
                                ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                                Log.d(TAG, "Статус: " + status + " Сообщние: " + response.message() + " ,Ошибка: " + errorBody);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Ошибка в onResponse", e);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UcozApi> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ошибка в onFailure: " + t);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception", e);
            }
```

Что я делаю не так? Буду признателен получить помощи!

Comment: У вас в ошибке сказано что отсутствует параметр, может вы какой то header не указали? Типа "Content-Type" : "json"  или что то типа того